# Rails can't require a javascript file that exists in the same folder

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails

Just deployed a Rails 5.x application and installed a theme. The theme's contents are located within the `app/assets/javascripts/theme-js` and `app/assets/stylesheets/theme-files` folders.

Inside of the `app/assets/javascripts/application.js` file includes the following:

```
//= require jquery
//= require jquery_ujs
//= require_tree .

// Required for the SmartAdmin theme
//= require theme-js/app.config.js.erb
//= require theme-js/app.js
```

And inside of the `app/assets/javascripts/theme-js`  folder are have the following files (included with the theme):

- app.config.js.erb
- app.js
- application.js

The problem that I'm having is that inside of the `application.js` file contains a line that states: `//= require app.config`, but Rails generates me an error stating the following:

> couldn't find file 'app.config' with type 'application/javascript'

Even though `app.config.js.erb` is in the same folder as `application.js`. Is there any reason why this would happen? Can't figure out why this won't work. I've even tried `//= require app.config.js` and `//= require app.config.js.erb` and neither one of them work.

I noticed that `//= require ./app.config` appears to work whereas `//= require app,config` doesn't. Something new with Rails 5.x perhaps? I'd have to modify all of the require statements to fit this unless I'm missing something.

Comment: Did you add the file to the `config/initializers/assets.rb` file?

Comment: I don't have anything in my old Rails app in that file, other than a precompile assets line, so not quite sure if I absolutely need to because I'm using Rails 5.x. Also, there's about 100 require statements in this application.js file, and more in some of the other files as well.

Answer (score 0):

Problem solved. Just needed to add the custom `theme-js` and `theme-css` folder to the assets pipeline so that Rails can search those folders for the appropriate files when using `//= require <file>`. Assuming this is what I needed to do, although I'm not sure if it's best practice.